# Querying if an int is inside of an array column, Postgres with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with a column of type integer array.
Given an integer as input I want to query for the rows where this column named
tipo_propiedad contains the input integer.
Directly in Postgres that may work by using && operator and casting the input int to an array.
The thing is that using this:

```
Zone.where("tipo_propiedad && ?", [].push(type)).count
```

Where type is the input integer, gives

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "zonas" WHERE (tipo_propiedad && 1)
>   PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] && integer

I also tried with

```
Zone.where("tipo_propiedad && ?", [5].push(type))
```

because tipo_propiedad would only have 1, 2 or 3 inside and that gives

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "zonas" WHERE (tipo_propiedad && 5,1)
>   PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer[] && integer

I'm also using squeel but that gem doesn't have any operator to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do either

```
Zone.where("'?' = ANY (tipo_propiedad)", 1)
```

or

```
Zone.where("tipo_propiedad && ARRAY[?]", 1)
                     # or "&& '{?}'"
```