# ActiveRecord check if any value in array matches value in array with postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I have an array of ints and I need to find any record where one of the ints in my array matches any of the ints in the array stored in postgres using active record.

The closest I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27863120/2558108) which works for searching an array with one int but not for searching with an array.

What would be the best way to find records in this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution that works

```
Model.where('array_in_db && ARRAY[?]::integer[]', [1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best approach would be to use the overlap (&&) postgres operator to do what you want to achieve.

Have a look at the postgres documentation on the same here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html.

Query would look something on the lines of :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column && {value1,value2};
```

Edit: Improving the answer.

In ActiveRecord, you can either build that query with a simple where clause call, or better yet install the https://github.com/DockYard/postgres_ext gem for even easier integration.

If you install the postgres extension gem you can simply do :

```
Model.where.overlap(column: [value1, value2])
```